# DocuSign Connect Local Testing

Tags: docusignapi

I am doing some local testing for DocuSign Connect.
I have a dynamic IP address so I am unable to set the URL under DocuSign Connect to publish messages to my local server.
I am thinking of simulating a POST request from DocuSign Connect and I'm wondering if anyone has a sample POST request that I can tap on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the GUIDs, IPs and signer/sender information, but here's an example of a Envelope - Delivered message with the following configuration:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>testemail+12354@test.com</Email>
                <UserName>Signer Name</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2016-06-20T15:41:01.78</Sent>
                <Delivered>2016-06-20T15:41:26.133</Delivered><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Status>Delivered</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress>123.123.12.22</RecipientIPAddress><CustomFields/>
                <TabStatuses>
                    <TabStatus>
                        <TabType>SignHere</TabType>
                        <Status>Active</Status>
                        <XPosition>412</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>207</YPosition>
                        <TabLabel>Signature 1</TabLabel>
                        <TabName>Sign Here</TabName><TabValue/>
                        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber><OriginalValue/></TabStatus>
                    <TabStatus>
                        <TabType>DateSigned</TabType>
                        <Status>NA</Status>
                        <XPosition>859</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>364</YPosition>
                        <TabLabel>Date Signed</TabLabel>
                        <TabName>Date Signed</TabName><TabValue/>
                        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber><OriginalValue/></TabStatus>
                </TabStatuses>
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <EsignAgreementInformation>
                    <AccountEsignId>xxxxxxxx-b74b-4c31-b8f7-fe33af69a315</AccountEsignId>
                    <UserEsignId>xxxxxxxx-7672-436b-bcf9-a45c9b53247c</UserEsignId>
                    <AgreementDate>2016-06-20T15:41:26.133</AgreementDate>
                </EsignAgreementInformation>
                <RecipientId>xxxxxxxx-36be-49b5-8c63-c256b1f261ab</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2016-06-20T15:41:46.2761003</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>xxxxxxxx-f2ac-489d-babd-d7554ca1b2de</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>Please DocuSign this document: SamplePDF.pdf</Subject>
        <UserName>Test Sender</UserName>
        <Email>senderemail@test.com</Email>
        <Status>Delivered</Status>
        <Created>2016-06-20T15:40:33.64</Created>
        <Sent>2016-06-20T15:41:01.827</Sent>
        <Delivered>2016-06-20T15:41:26.18</Delivered>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2016-06-20T15:40:33.64</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>Test Sender</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail>senderemail@test.com</ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>12.163.90.22
        </SenderIPAddress><EnvelopePDFHash/>
        <CustomFields>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>Storage?</Name>
                <Show>True</Show>
                <Required>False</Required><Value/></CustomField>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>AccountId</Name>
                <Show>false</Show>
                <Required>false</Required>
                <Value>123456</Value>
                <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>AccountName</Name>
                <Show>false</Show>
                <Required>false</Required>
                <Value>DocuSign Demo</Value>
                <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>AccountSite</Name>
                <Show>false</Show>
                <Required>false</Required>
                <Value>demo</Value>
                <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>SamplePDF.pdf</Name><TemplateName/>
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
    <TimeZone>AUS Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
    <TimeZoneOffset>10</TimeZoneOffset>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

If Include Documents and Include CoC are ticked each document in the envelope (including CoC) will come through in a separate byte stream:

```
<DocumentPDFs>
  <DocumentPDF>
    <Name>SamplePDF.pdf</Name>
    <PDFBytes>
    {bytestream}
    </PDFBytes>
    <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
    <DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType>
  </DocumentPDF>
  <DocumentPDF>
    <Name>CertificateOfCompletion_{envelopeI}.pdf</Name>
    <PDFBytes>
    {bytestream}
    </PDFBytes>
    <DocumentType>SUMMARY</DocumentType>
  </DocumentPDF>
</DocumentPDFs>
```

Comment: just wondering if I check include certificate of completion. will this be appended to the document pdf? if I want it separated, does it mean I should do another api call to get the COC

Comment: Each document (and CoC) comes through separately in a bytestream

Comment: Does this mean the document will be one byte stream and the COC another byte stream?

Comment: Each document will be in a separate byte stream. See my updated Answer for example.